# C#: Clean recently used files from jumplists

Tags: c#, windows-7, jump-list

Is there a way to clean the some items form the Windows Jump-List using C#? 
(An applications Jump-List appears when you click right on the applications icon in the Windows 7 Taskbar.)

I would like to clean the menu items representing the recently closed files but I'd like to keep the other menu items.

For example I'd like to clean the items of Google Chromes recently closed websites under the headline "Recently closed". I'd also like to keep the application specific menu items under the headline "Tasks".

All the menu information is stored in some binary files in the directory "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\".

It is possible to delete these files, but if I do so I not only delete the list of recently used files but I also delete the application specific menu items, too.

I'm looking for a way to find and clean the menu items representing the most recently used files for any applicatins Jump-List using C# code. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Really, applications are not supposed to do this. An application might decide not to show recently used items at all, but taking items out of the recently used list is not such a good idea. Furthermore, you're not asking "how can my application I'm writing do such a thing for itself" but rather "how can I write an application that will stop some other application from doing something?" Well, you can try, but you know possibly the other application will just put things back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is possible to user the Winodws API Code Pack for C#?

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack